# insert values from an object where keys are columnn names

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `json_encoded string` where `keys` are `column names` and need to insert corresponding `values`

```
$str = {"fname":"lorem","sname":"ipsum","nick":"dolor"};
```

`fname` `sname` `nick` - are column names - and need to insert `lorem` `ipsum` `dolor`

I made an object - `$obj = json_decode($str);` - but what then?

in a plain example - without the object - it would be like this:

```
function insert($fname, $sname, $nick){
    $sq = "insert into table (fname, sname, nick) values (:afname, :asname, :anick)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute([
        ":afname" => $fname, // lorem
        ":asname" => $sname, // ipsum
        ":anick" => $nick  // dolor
    ]);

}
```

how to do this using the given object?

Comment: Have you tried something like `print_r($obj);` to see what it contains and then translate the values?

Comment: @NigelRen - translate the values into... what? And why? They are the right values, ready for insert?

Comment: If you look at the values in the object, then look at the function you are calling.  Which parts of the object go to which fields in the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making object, just pass these in `insert` method(use your above mentioned `insert` method)

```
$obj = json_decode($str);
insert($obj->fname, $obj->sname, $obj->nick);
```

If you wanna pass as an object in the function, you can do in following manner.

```
function insert($obj){
    $sq = "insert into table (fname, sname, nick) values (:afname, :asname, :anick)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute([
        ":afname" => $obj->fname, // lorem
        ":asname" => $obj->sname, // ipsum
        ":anick" => $obj->nick  // dolor
    ]);

}
```

If you want to use dynamically insert columns with their values. You can do so in following manner.

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

$sq = "insert into table (". implode(', ', array_keys($arr)) . ") values (" . implode(',',array_fill(0, count($arr),"?")) . ")";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute(array_values($arr));
```

Here

- `implode(', ', array_keys($arr))` - create a comma separated column names based on array keys.
- `implode(',',array_fill(0, count($arr),"?"))` - create `?` for prepared statement. Number of `?` would be equal to array length and then concatenated with `,`.
- `array_values($arr)` pass values as array.

Comment: I think this will work. Just want to know is there a way to say like this - `insert into table ($obj->keys) values ($obj->values - replaced by :a)`

Comment: yes, that also you can do. Look for `array_keys` and `array_values`.

Comment: `$obj` is not  `array` but  `object`

Comment: you can do this `$arr = json_decode($str, true)` and you'll get an array.

Comment: If you want to use prepared statement, let me give you a hint in answer itself. Will update answer.

Comment: I don't know how to make a hint in answer, but it would be fine if you could make a full example with arrays and prepared statement, pls

Comment: you're a `magic_master`. thanks again, especially for the explanation part